# Issue in viewing in-built dataset from cran such as Nile, Air Passengers etc

Tags: r, view, cran

i am new to programming and i have been trying to explore R by using some in-built dataset from CRAN. Recently, I have been facing issue in viewing the tables of Nile, Air Passengers etc. On running >View(Nile) instead of showing a table, it shows something different.
However I have no issues trying to view other datasets like iris. I am unable to understand why i am able to view only few in-built datasets. Kindly help me fix this issue
[This is how my screen shows up when I give  View command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY581.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**1) fortify.zoo** RStudio has replaced `View` with its own code causing the problem; however, this should work in both RStudio and on Windows in Rgui.  It converts the `ts` objects `AirPassengers` and `Nile` to data frames which RStudio's `View` can display.

```
library(zoo)

View(fortify.zoo(AirPassengers))
View(fortify.zoo(Nile))
```

**2) as.zoo** These also work in both Rgui in Windows and Rstudio by forcing the use of R's `View` function rather than Rstudio's `View`.   In Rgui we don't need the `utils:::` part (although it won't hurt).

```
utils:::View(as.zoo(AirPassengers))
utils:::View(as.zoo(Nile))
```

**3) data.frame**  Another approach that works in both RStudio and Rgui for Windows but is somewhat verbose is:

```
View(data.frame(time(AirPassengers), AirPassengers))
View(data.frame(time(Nile), Nile))
```

**4) as.data.frame**  This one only partly works -- it shows the data but not the index.

In R (not RStudio) `as.data.frame` is automatically applied to the argument of `View` so the `as.data.frame` is actually superfluous and one could just write `View(Nile)`, etc.

The reason that the index is not shown is that `as.data.frame.ts` drops the index whereas `as.data.frame.zoo` invoked in (2) puts the index into the row names which `View` displays.

```
View(as.data.frame(AirPassengers))
View(as.data.frame(Nile))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because they are different types of objects

```
> str(Nile)
 Time-Series [1:100] from 1871 to 1970: 1120 1160 963 1210 1160 1160 813 1230 1370 1140 ...

> str(AirPassengers)
 Time-Series [1:144] from 1949 to 1961: 112 118 132 129 121 135 148 148 136 119 ...

> str(iris)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

`iris` is a data.frame, and the other time series.